# How to remove \" from a string

Tags: javascript, json

```
var str = "\\\"";
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(response.data).replace(str, "");
```

This code dont work.
sample JSON:

```
[{ ID: 1, text: \"Meat\" }
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You should fix the source, not the symptoms.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question. I strongly assume that just replacing backslashes is a terrible approach.

Comment: What do you want to get? You should not mess with the value returned by [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) or you won't be able to decode it back (because you'll end up with invalid JSON).

Comment: @axiac I ended up editing the JSON result to String then back to JSON.
The problem is--yeah I think its invalid now because i got an error.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. Think of it as an encoded data (or encrypted, if you like it more). It **is not** something you can edit. Only [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) knows how to decode it, to get back data structures similar to those used to generate the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @str commented right. But if you want to force fully remove these then you need to replace the charecters

```
response.data = response.data.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Comment: @SangramBadi So you agree to fix the source but suggest to fix the symptoms instead? Interesting.

Comment: @str as you commented above is correct. but below your comment @dscytheProductions commented as `Its just a sample string inside the JSON. I just want to remove the \`

Comment: @SangramBadi I have a problem now converting it back to JSON so I can use it as data
$scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                                            data: data, //here <------
                                            schema: {
                                                model: {
                                                    children: "Rights"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

Comment: @dscytheProductions That is exactly why I expected the replace approach to be terrible and asked for a full code example in the first place...

Comment: @SangramBadi your code is working removing those slashes. Now, I cant reverse it back to JSON. Or how can I just make it as an object.
Sorry I just started angular months ago.

Comment: it means you are getting response from a URL not a hardcoded data

Comment: if yes then you need to change it in backend.

Comment: @SangramBadi It is fully working now guys! After studying the JSON format i realized i should not delete the (quotation marks). Thanks everyone! Cheers!